# How to generate sparse complex-valued unitary matrices with given density?

Tags: matlab, random, sparse-matrix

For my research, I need to generate sparse (complex-values) unitary matrices at random from a uniform distribution. It is not a problem for me to generate the generic unitary matrices using, e.g., this code:

```
X = (randn(n) + i*randn(n))/sqrt(2);
[Q,R] = qr(X);
R = diag(diag(R)./abs(diag(R)));
U = Q*R;
```

However, I do not know how to generate the sparse version of the matrix, neither I haven't found in the internet. Could you, please, guide me on that?

Comment: did you checked the [sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function?

Comment: I know how to generate sparse matrix, but not a unitary one. Plus, the essential requirement is that it should be generated from a uniform distribution. The sparse function does not solve either of these problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. If you type `X = sparse((randn(n) + i*randn(n))/sqrt(2))` you will create a sparse matrix. Every operation you did so for will return a sparse matrix and, at the end, you will get the matrix `U` as sparse. Another option is to declare `U_sparse = sparse(U)`. It will get you a sparse matrix and a unitary one. Either way, you can check that `norm(U*U'-eye(n))` is very close to zero, so this is indeed a unitary matrix and a sparse one.

Comment: By sparse I meant that the resulted matrix should have proper fraction of zero entries. This is not about the representation form of a matrix. If I understand correct,  the sparse command does is that it takes a matrix written as an array and convert it into the sparse representation, while not changing the actual data.

Comment: I see. Can you provide us an example?

Comment: Say, I want to generate a sparse 5-by-5 unitary matrix with only 6 non-zero elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself with the following algorithms.

This first one is a bit easier but it is not mathematically equivalent to uniformly sampling the space of all random matrices of a certain sparsity.

1. Produce a block diagonal unitary matrix.  That is, if you want an N x N sparse unitary matrix, produce k random dense unitary matrices matrices of size n1 x n1, n2 x n2, n3 x n3,..., nk x nk, where n1 + n2 + ... + nk = N.  Then put these together to get an N x N block diagonal unitary matrix.
2. Shuffle the bases to get a non-block-diagonal matrix; that is, shuffle the rows by applying some permutation and then apply the same permutation to the columns. The shuffled matrix will still be unitary.  Now you have your general sparse unitary matrix.

You need code to randomly produce suitable numbers n1, n2, ..., nk.  I think that's the only tricky part.

Another method is simply "brute force".  Generate N mutually orthogonal unit vectors of length N, where each of the vectors has mostly zero entries.  Then use these as the rows (or columns) of your matrix.

You would need some sort of a random algorithm to set the number of nonzero entries in each vector, then use a modified version of the Graham-Schmidt method to produce the actual vectors.  In the end you can further randomize by shuffling the bases.